# Adding a person who is not a member to the organization

Tags: trello, account-management, trello-organization

My boss wants to use this system. I set myself up, the organization and some boards. He wants me to add him to be allowed to see and make comments.

He is not a user yet and he wants me to set everything up. How do I set up his account for him so he can see my things and any projects that he wants to do without me?

Answer (score 1):

I just set up gmail addresses for a few team members and got them onto the board that way. It's a bit of a long winded workaround but it gets things up and running and means they come into a functional team setup from the off.
I used keepass to store all the usernames and passwords so logging into different gmail accounts to process the invitations is a lot easier.

Things may be getting easier, this feature is currently in testing https://trello.com/c/DE9Kq6vV